# How do I change the default color of a new object?

Tags: objects, customization

I add a new cube to the scene, but it's teal and I want a different color:

[image]

I assume it should be in the User Preferences, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered I had [MatCap Shading](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/shading.html) enabled, so all I had to do was turn off MatCap here:

3D View -> Properties (<kbd>N</kbd>) -> Shading -> turn off Matcap

[image]